# Email error message illegal option s in ksh script

Tags: ksh

I am using below code to send mail using ksh script in unix

```
echo "Hi. here is my message body" | mail -s "test mail ksh" "abc@xyz.com,efg@xyz.com"
```

But i keep getting the below error

```
    mail: illegal option -- s
    usage: mail [+] [-epqr] [-f file]
    mail [-dt] persons
```

Please help with the correct format to use.

Answer (score 0):

Some `mail`(1) implementation has no `-s subject` option. Use `mailx`(1) instead if available. Or use `sendmail`(1) or other mailers with suitable options and input for it.